# What is the GetHashCode method for?

Tags: .net

What is the `GetHashCode` method of a string object?

Is this the same as when you compute the hashcode of something? But `GetHashCode` returns int, shouldn't it return a byte array?

thanks!

Comment: This question is quite general. Why would a hash code be a byte array? If you tell us why you think that perhaps it might help clear up the misunderstanding.

Comment: because I've used ComputeHash method from hash objects only...

Answer (score 1):

What it should return depends on the size of the hash. If the hash can serve its purpose with the relatively small size of 32 bits, then returning it as an `int` makes practical sense. This was also (and I suppose it still is) common when calculating the `crc32` checksum, which as its name implies is 32 bits long.

The purpose of the hash in .NET is explained in the documentation as other answers mention. In short, the hash is used in .NET to:

- Coarsely compare two objects for equality (you know they are not equal if the hashes do not match)
- Disperse objects across the length of a hashtable when they are put into one

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you what a hashcode is for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

> A hash code is a numeric value that is
>   used to identify an object during
>   equality testing. It can also serve as
>   an index for an object in a
>   collection.

Note that the default implementation of Object.GetHashCode returns an integer.  A hash doesn't necessarily have to return a byte array to be a hash.

And this will tell you about the string hashcode:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx